# How to remove brackets, quotes from table?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have a column `uuid` looking like as shown in the picture. It is a JSON type. I want to remove 
 the square brackets from each row and then the quotes (which I can remove using `JSON_UNQUOTE`). I tried using `JSON_EXTRACT(uuid, '$[0]')` but with this, I can only select one value at a time e.g. `"5f5616fd88b3484bb636e6dbf5a702b6"` not all the values inside the square brackets at once.

Once this is done, I want to remove quotes from each value and then again add brackets back. After this I want to export it as csv and use it for building a network graph using `Networkx` python library.

I am very open to suggestions, if my idea is wrong. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: You should do all this work in code / excel-macro. Not in the DB ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with JSON functions, because what you are trying to produce is not valid JSON.

However, you can process the json value with string functions. If you just want to replace the embedded double quotes, you can do:

```
replace(uuid, '"', '')
```

Comment: damn, that was easy. I read about `replace` but thought it will make the changes permanently into the DB. Anyways, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to split the data into separate rows as well as remove the [] and ""

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(value,3,LEN(TRIM(REPLACE(value,'"',''))) - 2) AS column_alias
FROM
schema.table_name table_alias
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(table_alias.column_name,',')
```

Hope this helps!