# How to remove brackets from JSON results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

My apologies in advance for the naive question - seeking MySQL help to remove brackets [ ] from my results.

I referenced a question in here ([How to remove brackets, quotes from table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60600266/how-to-remove-brackets-quotes-from-table)) which was extremely helpful, but I was only able to figure out how to remove one bracket only.

This is the line of SQL I am using:

```
 COALESCE(REPLACE(static_demographics.race, '[', ''), '')   AS `Clients Race`,
```

My results ended up obviously removing just the one bracket:

```
Result
3]
```

I want to be able to remove the right bracket as well to leave the result only.
How would I be able to tweak the SQL to include BOTH brackets to be removed. I can see from my SQL that I'm clearly only referencing the left bracket, just not sure how to incorporate both. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: You can nest REPLACE() inside another REPLACE().

Comment: Why don't you use `JSON_EXTRACT()`?

Comment: @Barmar - Thank you for this suggestion. I'm not too familiar with JSON, still trying to research and get myself up to speed. 

How would utilize JSON_EXTRACT? I attempted it but clearly my syntax isn't correct because it only returned NULL values. Trying to search what the syntax should look like to extract the values.

Answer (score 0):

The result returned by `REPLACE()` is a string. You can use that as the input to another call to `REPLACE()`.

```
COALESCE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      static_demographics.race, 
      '[', ''),                 -- inner replace removes left bracket 
   ']', ''),                    -- outer replace removes right bracket
  '')                           -- default to empty string
```